# Correct way to enter date criteria in a parameter query

Tags: ms-access-2013

When I enter in criteria field for a date field like <#19-08-2018#, It works but when I want to enter as a parameter query and If I write there in the pop-up box  <#19-08-2018# , it gives the error "Data type mismatch in the criteria expression". Pl let me know the correct way to enter this type of criteria in parameter query.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way and that is I have to enter parameter criteria as < [Enter Date:] in the criteria field and then it works.